# Dreamweaver CS5 MAMP Site Definition Error

Tags: wordpress, dreamweaver, mamp

Hi Stackoverflow world,

I need help! I have set up a development stack with MySQL/PHP using MAMP. I am trying to create a WordPress theme and have downloaded all of the files to htdocs in the MAMP file system. The server works great, when I type in my localhost into Firefox everything shows up as it should.  However, when I go to edit in DreamWeaver none of the files will dynamically connect. I am getting an error that says the site definition is not correct for this server. Here is what I have done within DreamWeaver and WordPress to try to remedy the issue:

1) wp-config: I have set up the database name, username, password, and host:

```
dbname: AmplifyFinancial
username: admin
Pword: ****
host: localhost
```

2) I have set up the site information in "manage sites".

**Site**

```
site name: AmplifyFinancial
local site folder: /Applications/MAMP/htdocs/wordpress
```

**Servers**

```
name: AmplifyFinancial
connect using: local/network
server folder: /Applications/MAMP/htdocs/wordpress
web url: "http://localhost/wordpress/"
remote box unchecked and Test box checked
```

**testing server**

```
server model: PHP MySQL
```

**local info**

```
web URL: "http://localhost/wordpress/"
links relative to: document
enable cache is checked
```

Even after checking this information literally 10 times, I cannot figure out why DreamWeaver is saying there is a site definition error.  I even tried changing the username and password information in the wp-config file to both say "root".  This did not work.  I have heard that sometime permalinks can screw things up, but I am not sure how to chance this to see if that is my problem.  Anybody have any ideas?  I am super stuck here....

Answer (score 0):

You don't have to fill out the server, testing server and local info.. you can skip that part if you are just working locally.

And as far as the passwords go, that should be root / root